# Laravel Form model binding for image not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my edit form model binding, I'd like to display the vehicle images, I've the code in my view blade:

```
{!! Form::model($cedit, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['category.update', $cedit->id], 'files' => true]) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
       <img src="images/{{ $cedit->name }}"/>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

In order to access a resource you should use the `asset()` helper to get the full path for your public directory like this :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <img src="{{asset('/images/'.$cedit->name)}}">
</div>
```

Comment: How does this help?  Including a description of what you did, and why it helps, will increase the quality of your answer.